# Figure out which control is sending to form

Tags: vb.net, combobox

Is there a way to figure out which combobox's selectedchanged event is firing so I can send it to a new form?

I basically want to know which combobox is sending the request so I can put the appropriate text on the screen. Code below:

```
Private Sub cboDecision_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboLife1.SelectedIndexChanged, cboLife2.SelectedIndexChanged, cboLife3.SelectedIndexChanged
    If cboLife1.SelectedText = "Accept" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Yes")
    Else
        Dim dec As frmDeclined = New frmDeclined(Pass control name here??)
        dec.ShowDialog()

    End If
End Sub

Sub New(ctrlStep6 As ctrlStep6)
    InitializeComponent()

    step6 = ctrlStep6

    Code with name of person selected from the correct combobox here

    lblMember.Text = nameFromComboBox

End Sub
```

This is what I have so far but am stumped as to how the pass the name of the control to frmDeclined.

Comment: Yuo can try DirectCast(sender, Control).Name

Comment: I am including that as Answer so that future user can refer actual answer.Please accept that as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this to figure out which control field is the actual sender for the request.

```
DirectCast(sender, Control).Name
```